# Jamstack/Nuxt.js: Can I have Vue components inside a json?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jamstack

I know I can use `frontmatter-markdown-loader` to allow Vue components inside a markdown file. However, is there any similar solution for a scenario where my articles are stored in a JSON?

For example, the following works with `frontmatter-markdown-loader`:

```
---
date: 2015-10-21
title: My First Blog Post
---

Who moved my cheese cow mascarpone. Cheese on toast cheese on toast mozzarella bavarian bergkase emmental gouda cheese triangles. Croque monsieur dolcelatte macaroni cheese taleggio parmesan cheese triangles St. Agur blue cheese. Everyone loves cheese.

<cheese-slideshow />
```

Now, is there any similar solution for a scenario where my articles are stored in a JSON file instead of a .md?

Comment: what json? but sure, you can run the value through https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler